# Strong law of large numbers - Continuous martingales - Reference request

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, martingales, law-of-large-numbers, quadratic-variation

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F P)$ be a probability space with a filtration $\mathcal F_t$ and $M = (M_t,t\geq 0)$ be a real-valued continuous $\mathcal F_t$-martingale such that its quadratic variation satisfies $\langle M\rangle_\infty = \infty$ a.s. Then, the strong law of large numbers for martingales yields
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{M_t}{\langle M\rangle_t}=0,
$$
a.s. (see e.g. Lipster & Shirayev *Theory of Martingales*, Corollary 1.1, p. 144).

I'm looking for a reference for this result, but in the case of vector-valued continuous martingales. In particular, let $M$ be a vector-valued $\mathcal F_t$-martingale (with values in $\mathbb R^d$). In this case, the quadratic variation $\langle M \rangle$ is defined as the unique $Q = (Q_t, t \geq 0)$ with values in $\mathbb R^{d\times d}$ such that
$$
M_t \otimes M_t - Q_t
$$
is an $\mathcal F_t$-martingale (see e.g. Pavliotis & Stuart, *Multiscale Methods: Averaging and Homogenization*, Definition 3.18, p. 46).

What can we say in this case? For example, if $\langle M \rangle_t$ is a non-singular (thus in this case symmetric positive definite) matrix a.s. for all $t \geq 0$ and such that $\|\langle M\rangle_\infty\| = \infty$ a.s., can we say that
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty} \langle M \rangle_t^{-1} M_t = 0, \qquad \qquad (1)
$$
a.s. in $\mathbb R^d$?

**Example**

I give a simple example of a martingale I am interested in. Let $W$ be a one-dimensional Wiener process with natural filtration $\mathcal F_t$ and let $\beta = (\beta_t, t\geq 0)$ be a $\mathcal F_t$-adapted stochastic process with values in $\mathbb R^d$ and components $\beta_t = (\beta_t^{1}, \ldots, \beta_t^{d})^\top$. Then consider the $\mathcal F_t$-martingale
$$
M_t = \int_0^t \beta_s \, \mathrm{d} W_s = \begin{pmatrix}\int_0^t \beta_s^1 \, \mathrm{d} W_s, \ldots, \int_0^t \beta_s^d \, \mathrm{d} W_s \end{pmatrix}^\top.
$$
The quadratic variation of $M$ satisfies (by Itô isometry)
$$
\langle M \rangle_t=\int_0^t \beta_s \beta_s^\top \, \mathrm{d} s.
$$
Can we conclude something in the line of $(1)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method to solve your problem is use above mentioned result to each component
of $M_t=(M^{(1)}_t,\cdots, M^{(d)}_t) $, that is
\begin{equation*}
 \{\langle M^{(i)} \rangle_\infty=\infty, 1\le i\le d   \}
 \subset \{\lim_{t\to\infty} D_t^{-1} M_t=0\},   \qquad \text{a.s.}
\end{equation*}
where $D_t=\mathrm{diag}(\langle M^{(1)} \rangle_t ,\cdots, \langle M^{(d)} \rangle_t ) $
is a diagonal matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Theorem 1.3.4 (which means Theorem 3.4 in Chapter 1) in "Stochastic Differential Equations and Applications (2011)" written by Xuerong Mao. There, two results are given:

---

Let $M = \{M_t\}_{t\geq 0}$ be a real-valued continuous local martingale vanishing at $t = 0$. Then $$ \lim_{t \to \infty} \langle M\rangle_t = \infty \quad \text{a.s.} \implies \lim_{t \to \infty} M_t / \langle M\rangle_t = 0 \quad \text{a.s.}$$ and also
$$ \limsup_{t \to \infty} \langle M\rangle_t / t < \infty \quad \text{a.s.} \implies \lim_{t \to \infty} M_t / t = 0 \quad \text{a.s.}$$

Comment: How does this help on the multi-dimensional case?